# Theme inherited from Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar but still get crash for bottomAppbar

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

I'm trying to implement a bottomnavigationview and I followed the material tutorial. However I'm getting this error:

```
Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires 
  your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

I browsed here a bit and found that the majority didn't add the materialComponenets theme, I had added it as per the tutorial, but still, my app crashes with the above error .
This is my style.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="headlines" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">26sp </item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/poppins_extra_bold</item>
    <item name="fontWeight">700</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

and this is my main_activity.xml:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigationbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            style="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">


            <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
                android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/nav_bottom"
                app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
                app:fabCradleMargin="8dp"
                app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp"
                app:hideOnScroll="true"
                >

                <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
                    style="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/nav_bottom"
                    app:elevation="0dp"
                    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
                    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_bar">

                </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

            </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:maxImageSize="88dp"
            app:tint="@null"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/nav_bottom"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fox_home" />
```

Comment: Make sure you have added `MaterialComponents` for dark mode as well

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to . I've not specified any theme for dark mode.

Comment: Check in your themes.xml file

Comment: It's exactly as shown here.

Answer (score 0):

So I downgraded from alpha06 to `implementation com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0` and     `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'` and it worked. I also added a style to my themes.xml:

```
 <style name="AppThemeMaterial" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/rect_box</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orangehue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/beige_bg_rounded</item>
</style>
```

so my bottomAppBar.xml looks like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/navigationbarcurved"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeMaterial"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="5dp">
            //my bottom nav here
             </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```